# C++ Member Function Results Cache Implementation

Tags: c++, caching, c++11

I've got some function that take a long time but the results are always the same, so I wanted to cache the results. I've written a generic implementation of a results cache that can be inherited giving caching functionality to the derived class.

```
#include "includes.h"

// Interface so values can be stored polymophically in a vector
class CacheInterface
{
public:
  virtual ~CacheInterface(){}
  virtual std::string GetName() const = 0;
};

// Stores a cached value and its name
template <class T>
class CachedValue : public CacheInterface
{
public:
  CachedValue(const T & value, const std::string & name):
    _value(value),
    _name(name)
  {
  }

  std::string GetName() const
  {
    return _name;
  }

  void SetValue(const T & value)
  {
    _value = value;
  }

  T _value;
  std::string _name;
};


// Stores the cache results, can be inherited from or held as a member.
class ResultCache
{
public:
  template <class T> void AddToCache(const T & value, const std::string & name)
  {
    // Search if it is there
    for (shared_ptr<CacheInterface> & cache : _cached_items)
    {
      if (cache->GetName() == name)
      {
        shared_ptr<CachedValue<T>> cache_value (boost::reinterpret_pointer_cast<CachedValue<T>>(cache));
        cache_value->_value = value;
        return;
      }
    }

    // Make a new cache value and add it
    shared_ptr<CacheInterface> cached_item(new CachedValue<T>(value, name));
    _cached_items.push_back(cached_item);
  }

  // Returns true if cache exists for a name
  bool IsInCache(const std::string & name)
  {
    for (shared_ptr<CacheInterface> & cache : _cached_items)
    {
      if (cache->GetName() == name)
      {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  // Reads a value from the cache
  template <class T> void ReadFromCache(T & output, const std::string & name)
  {
    for (shared_ptr<CacheInterface> & cache : _cached_items)
    {
      if (cache->GetName() == name)
      {
        // Is reinterpret cast safe?
        shared_ptr<CachedValue<T>> cache_value (boost::reinterpret_pointer_cast<CachedValue<T>>(cache));
        output = cache_value->_value;
      }
    }
  }

  // Clears the cache values
  void ClearCache()
  {
    _cached_items.clear();
  }

  // Clear cache on copy and assign?


private:
  std::vector<shared_ptr<CacheInterface>> _cached_items;
};

// Macros simplified use in code.
#define IS_IN_CACHE(x) IsInCache(#x)
#define READ_FROM_CACHE(x) ReadFromCache(x, #x)
#define CACHE_RESULT(x) AddToCache(x, #x)
```

Usage:

```
#include "UnitTest++.h"
#include "resultcache.h"
#include "accuratetimer.h"


class TestCacheClass : public ResultCache
{
public:

  int LongFunction()
  {
    int i = 34;

    if (IS_IN_CACHE(i))
    {
      READ_FROM_CACHE(i);
      return i;
    }
    else
    {
      sleep(1);
      i = 9932;
      CACHE_RESULT(i);
      return i;
    }
  }
};


TEST(Cache1)
{
  TestCacheClass test_class;
  AccurateTimer timer;
  CHECK_EQUAL(test_class.LongFunction(), 9932);
  CHECK_CLOSE(timer.GetTimeDuration(), 1.0, 0.2);
  timer.Reset();
  CHECK_EQUAL(test_class.LongFunction(), 9932);
  CHECK_CLOSE(timer.GetTimeDuration(), 0.0, 0.2);
}
```

Is using reinterpret cast safe here?

Would this be faster if a std::map was used rather than std::vector, for finding a value from its name. I've seen that in many places a std::vector is much faster due to the pre-fetcher.

Comment: You are complicating your code for the sake of inheritance. There are several simpler techniques to cache results, which do not need class hierarchies. A simple std::vector or std::list may suffice.

Comment: A vector or list would be required for every different return type. I only want to write the code to do something once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> in many places a std::vector is much faster due to the pre-fetcher.

By prefetcher I assume you mean the CPU branch prediction and L1 cache?  Or are you referring to something else?  The speed of that over map depends a lot on the size of the cache, and the items in the cache.  If it's relatively few items then vector can be faster, but if not, then use Map - as the vector gets large then the O(log(n)) of map or O(1) of unordered map will be faster than O(n). [ and if it's small, you may be better off valuing simpler code instead of a limited performance gain. ]

To answer your original question, it isn't safe to reinterpret-cast a virtual interface pointer to a concrete type because the compiler could modify the vtable if you change the inheritance of the derived class (e.g. to inherit two interfaces).  You want static-cast.

Comment: Prefecher as in past pseudo L4 cache, memory latency is FAR longer than branch prediction failure. If L1-3 cache does not have a value, it has to come from RAM. The prefecher reads more than it is asked too and puts the values in L3 cache on the CPU so reads to data aligned near to it will be faster. This does not work with pointers that are all over the shop, only array like structures such as vectors.

Comment: I understand what you're referring to.  However, if your data structures are large the complexity class of O(log(n)) can easily make up the difference vs. O(n).  You can also implement custom allocators that put the nodes in a memory space with cache locality. (default allocators are notoriously average, performance wise.) There are multiple options - but relatively few system level applications require that level of optimization.